# Student search project jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a project that requires me to add a search bar to a page that has a list of students names and email addresses and once the form is submitted only show students who have the characters typed in the search bar either on email address or student name.

So far I have the search bar appended and have started a function that listens for the click event on the button and adds the value from the input to a variable.

I thought I could do an if statement that checks if the list item contains the input variable I created and just add a class that I can then do another if statement later to hide or show based on what class it contains.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//set number of students to show on each page 
var inputValue;
var showStudents = 10;
//append search bar to the page
$(".page-header").append('<div class="student-search"><input placeholder="Search for students..."><button>Search</button></div>');
//add pagination to the page
$(".page").append('<div class="pagination"><ul></ul></div>');

//make page display 10 students at a time

//make search input only show students that contain that letter.
//use contains to add an ID?/class? to the student list item that matches the value in the input field.
//display the students that have said ID/class and hide the others. 
$("button").click(function() {
    //store the value of the input search into a variable
    inputValue = $("input").val();
    console.log(inputValue);
    //filter the list items by the input value and add CSS


        if ('.student-details h3:contains(inputValue)') {
        $('.student-details h3').addClass('showstudent')
    }
});
```

});

Obviously my issue is that once I write this it adds the class to all .student-details h3 items, not just the ones that contain the inputValue, and I cannot use "this" because it just adds the class to the button.  Is this the best way to code this?  Should I just convert my students list to an array and have the value of the input search the array and return the results into a new array?  I am sort of lost here!  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
$('.student-details h3').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == inputValue) {
        $(this).addClass('showstudent');
    }
}
```